# Prevent object from casting shadow in Eevee

Tags: light

How do?
One answer says to set Shadow Mode to none in the settings of the material, but this doesn't work in this case for some reason. The light is spot.

[image: Shadow appears]

Answer (score 1):

FOR EEVEE:

make a material for the object and go to material properties > setting > shadow mode > none

**Edit:** Use contact shadows for small distances. if you want good shadows make the clips start of the light smaller and shadow resolution higher!
contact shadows are only for very small details that resolution of shadow map can't cover.

[image]

Comment: Is that different than what's in the screenshot in my question?

Comment: Sorry didn't notice, yeah then you use contact shadows wrongly. it's only for small distances.

Comment: Edited the answer. Also someone should report this as a bug!

Answer (score 0):

You could Use a light path node in the material and connect the is shadow to a mix between your material and a transparent shader

You can disable shadows for that light.

You might be able to disable shadows in the object settings or material settings as well.

Answer (score -3):

Try adding emmesion to the yellow wall behind the object. The shadow won't appear on the wall, but the wall will glow. Just a warning if you don't want that.

Comment: That may prevent the shadow from being visible, but it's not the answer to my question.